# Convert std::string from UTF8, UTF16, ISO88591 to Hexadecimal

Tags: encoding, utf-8, c++14, utf-16, iso-8859-1

I try to Encoding the std::string from UTF8,... to Hexadecimal. What I can't do right now is that I can't get the decimal value of each character of the input string to convert it if the input string contains special character which is from the Code Page Identifiers(windows-1258) include Vietnamese character.

At first, I will get the decimal value and then convert it to Binary and then to Hexadecimal. s is my input string. s = "Ồ".

```
void StringUtils::strToBinary(wstring s, string* result)
{
    int n = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        wchar_t c = s[i];
        long val = long(c);
        std::string bin = "";
        while (val > 0)
        {
            (val % 2) ? bin.push_back('1') :
                bin.push_back('0');
            val /= 2;
        }
        reverse(bin.begin(), bin.end());
        result->append(convertBinToHex(bin));
    }
}

std::string StringUtils::convertBinToHex(std::string temp) {
    long long binaryValue = atoll(temp.c_str());
    long long dec_value = 0;
    int base = 1;
    int i = 0;


    while (binaryValue) {
        long long last_digit = binaryValue % 10;

        binaryValue = binaryValue / 10;

        dec_value += last_digit * base;

        base = base * 2;

    }
    char hexaDeciNum[10];
    while (dec_value != 0)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        temp = dec_value % 16;
        if (temp < 10)
        {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 48;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 55;
            i++;
        }
        dec_value = dec_value / 16;
    }
    std::string str;
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        str = str + hexaDeciNum[j];
    }
    return str;
}
```

If my input only contain "Ồ" this is what my expected output

```
UTF8 : E1BB92
UTF16 : FEFF 1ED2
UTF16BE : 1ED2
UTF16LE : D21E
```

This how I do it in Java

```
    Charset charset = Charset.forName(Enum.valueOf(Encoding.class, encodingType).toString());
    ByteBuffer buffer = charset.newEncoder().encode(CharBuffer.wrap(inputString.toCharArray()));
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.limit()];
    buffer.get(bytes, 0, buffer.limit());
    result = new ByteField(bytes);
    return result;
            }
```

Comment: "*to Hexadecimal*" Hexadecimal is not a text encoding format. It's a way of representing numbers. Are you trying to represent the numerical value of code units in hex?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want right now. What I need is the way to get the decimal value of special character like "Ồ" which would be 7,891

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm that is not what Nicol asked.  Do you want to output the hex representation of the ENCODED UTF-8 CODEUNITS or the DECODED UNICODE CODEPOINTS?  `Ồ` is Unicode codepoint `U+1ED2`, which is decimal 7890 (not 7891, which would be `ồ` instead). `U+1ED2` is encoded in UTF-8 codeunits as `E1 BB 92`. Which representation are you looking for? I'm assuming you want the CODEPOINT not the CODEUNITS, right? That requires your code to PARSE AND DECODE THE UTF-8 DATA (ie, convert it to UTF-32), which your code is not doing. You already have UTF-8 and UTF-16 outputs, just add UTF-32 too.

Comment: I have edited my post to make sure that you understand what I mean.

Comment: So codepoint of "Ồ" is `1ED2`(which is my UTF16BE output) and the codeunit of "Ồ" is `E1 BB 92`(which is my UTF8 output). I don't get it, I just want to represent the input string into Hex but following my Java code output, the result is both in ENCODED UTF-8 CODEUNITS and DECODED UNICODE CODEPOINTS